# How to store location of visitor's profile on mysql database on php using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to store this in phpMyAdmin Database.
without showing the user that the location is stored

Comment: "without showing the user that the location is stored"; why is that?

Comment: Use AJAX to send it to a PHP script on the server.

Comment: First, That's just unethical. You should always let the user know you are accessing and storing their location. Second, why is this tagged as `PHP`?

Comment: I think browsers ask the user for permission before letting a script use location services, so you can't do this without the user's knokwledge.

Comment: @JeroenHeier  I mean that I don't want to show location coordinates on web page, I just want to store the coordinates in database using php

Comment: @AmitMerchant its not hidden that I am getting user's location, it will notify in the user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to send the location to the certain php file (like `geo.php`) using AJAX or any other request. And in the `geo.php` you accept the data and write it to the database. Look for [Ajax Post Request](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax of jquery to store data when you get position info

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in pc. dont run it on snippet because it needs you permission of location.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo1");
var y = document.getElementById("demo2");
var z = document.getElementById("demo3");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition1);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition2);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition3);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition1(position) {
    alert("showPosition1");
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showPosition2(position) {
    alert("showPosition2");
    y.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showPosition3(position) {
    alert("showPosition3");
    z.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know this but i want to store this coordinates in my database using php